# Generic constraints that allow Type to be 2 different classes

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics, constraints

I have a generic function in VB.Net. I also have two classes called `A` and `B`. Is it possible to allow the generic constraints on my function to allow the Type to be either class `A` or `B`? Class `A` and `B` do not share any base classes except for object.

Comment: doesn't sound very generic, why not just declare an overloaded method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's not possible. I suggest you create an interface with the common API of the two classes and make both classes implement that interface.

Answer (score 0):

While I recently focus on learning Java I discovered that exactly this is possible. When declaring generic parameters it is possible to combine multiple generic constraints by using the "&" operator. It looks as follows:

```
public class List<T extends IInterface1 & IInterface2> {
...
}
```

My first thought on this was that I would appreciate using this in .NET :-)

Comment: .NET and C# also support multiple constraints. But you cannot have a constraint of the sort x OR y, only x AND y. E.g. `void foo<T>() where T : IEnumerable, new()` requires T to be an enumerable type AND have a default constructor. But there is no way to say it must either be enumerable OR have a default constructor. Pity, because it would in fact quite be handy in several situations.